# Time to merge sorted lists into single sorted list?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given `logN` sorted lists each of size `N*logN`. What is the total time required to merge them into single sorted list?

```
A) O(NlogN)
B) O(N)
C) O(NloglogN)
D) O(Nlog(N/logN))
```

I tried solving it by taking N=4. But no option is satisfying.

Comment: Merging  `m` previously sorted lists is `O(m * n)`. If your are including the time to sort `m` lists then the time is `O(m * n lg n) + O (m * n)`, which is `O(m * n lg n)`

Comment: It is given that all lists are sorted initially. I also got( N*logN*logN), but there is no option?

Comment: @turingcomplete Logarithms don't work like that. My guess is that whoever made this exercise confused (logN)^2 and log(N^2) -- which *is* O(logN))

Comment: @JohnColeman ah yes, I confused lg a *lg b with lg(ab).

Comment: Well that depends on what algorithm you use. There are much better ways to k-way merge than the naive approach of just use linear-time merge k-1 times

Comment: @NiklasB. Since the resulting list will have size `N*(logN)^2` I don't see how you can do anything better.

Comment: @JohnColeman Ok, but you can't achieve that time bound using log N-1 naive merges. If you do that, you get time N log^3 N

Comment: @NiklasB. - Oops, sorry, I didn't go through the question properly. I deleted that comment. And, the answer below is a good one.

Comment: The problem statement isn't correct, double check it.

Comment: its c) O(NloglogN).  check this video with same example at the end.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfmaf4QpVTw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answers are a bit off, one way I know of doing it is the following:

**Merging K sorted lists of size M Using Min Heap:**

1. Create a MinHeap of the first k elements in the sorted lists - can be done in `O(K)` time.
2. While the MinHeap isn't empty:

   2.1. Take out the minimal Item - `O(log(K))` and place it in the sorted output.

   2.2. Take the next element from the list the item from 2.1 came from and add it to the MinHeap - `O(log(K))`

**Time Complexity:** `O(K) + O(K * M * log(K)) = O(K * M * log(K))`

And in our case :

`O(K*M*log(K)) = O(log(N) * N * log(N) * log(log(N))` =  **`O(N * log^2(N) * log(log(N))`**

**Edit:**
As suggested here, another approach would be merging all the lists in pairs:

**Merging K sorted lists of size M by merging pairs:**

1. Put all lists in a single list L.
2. while |L|>1 :

   2.1. Divide L into pairs (a,b) and merge lists a and b into c - for lists of size M that would be an `O(M)` merge.

   2.2. Put all the merged lists (c's) into a single list L (replacing previous L).
3. The only list in L is the result.

**Time Complexity Analysis:**
On each iteration we go through all elements - O(MK) and merge, log(K) iterations will result in O(log(K) * MK) = O(N * log^2(N) * log(log(N))

Comment: You should prefer writing `log ^2(N)` as `(log N)^2`.; An upvote for the solution too.

Comment: FWIW, in this scenario with equally-sized lists you can achieve the same time bound easier without the use of a heap: Just merge the first with the second list, the 3rd with the 4th and so on, then continue to merge in a binary-tree like fashion. You have log K levels, each with work K * M, which sums up to O(log K * K * M)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Why? `log^2(N)` is not rare notation and is analogous to notation for powers of a trig function. `(log N)^2` *is* more common -- but not to the extent that someone should be censured for the other notation.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I didn't sue him for writing in that manner! I just asked if he could use a more popular version, so that others could understand it too. It's about understandability of all who reads this answer in future too.(And writing `log ^2(N)` is generally considered not a good practice)

Comment: @NiklasB. - Maybe I got different lessons from my teacher in school, and might be Indian authors of mathematics books(at least the book through which I was taught in high school) preferred the other way around.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful All this is somewhat tangential -- but you phrased your original comment as an imperative -- "You *should* prefer writing...". I see no reason for the imperative though I have no problem with you stating your preference (in fact -- I share your preference here).

Answer (score 1):

None of the propositions are possible, just for the reason that the final list has size `N.Log²(N)`.